# sudo in php exec()

Tags: php, linux, sudo

I don't know what the deal is here…

So I want to run an applescript: `sudo osascript myscript.scpt`

This works fine in the terminal, but not when I execute it via PHP's `exec()`; nothing happens. The console says

```
no tty present and no askpass program specified ; TTY=unknown ; …
```

I did my research, and it seems I'm missing the password for the `sudo` command. I tried a couple different ways to get around this, including:

- writing `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` in `/etc/sudoers`
- and `proc_open()` instead of `exec()`

none of which seem to be working, consequently driving me CrAzY!

So basically, is there a clear-cut way to get PHP to execute a simple terminal command?

EDIT: to clarify, `myscript.scpt` is a simple appleScript that changes the onscreen UI (for a larger project).  In theory, simply `osascript myscript.scpt` should be enough, however the `sudo` is for some reason necessary to invoke *some* response from the system.  If the `sudo` could be somehow eliminated, I don't think I would be having this permissions problem.

Comment: There are ways to address this, but the best way is to probably make `myscript.script` run without root privileges.

Comment: Any way you could go about this is technically a bad idea. You either give PHP access to sudo without needing a password, or use a setuid helper script that always runs with root privileges. Neither one is quite sane when dealing with a PHP front end. Can you update your question to tell us what `myscript.scpt` is actually accomplishing ?

Answer (score 18):

It sounds like you need to set up passwordless sudo. Try:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: osascript myscript.scpt
```

Also comment out the following line (in /etc/sudoers via visudo), if it is there:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

Comment: I tried adding this to etc/sudoers, but no dice.  I still get "no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: Did you have any luck commenting out the requiretty line?

Comment: Nope.  it wasn't in the file at all.
I'm starting to agree with Matchu (below) about all this security stuff.  If my system makes it this difficult, it's probably for a good security reason.

Comment: I think that is a wise decision :) Despite me trying to help answer your original question, I do think that using sudo in a webapp has the potential to intoduce a lot of security headaches.

Comment: Where in need to put %admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: @SunilBhawsar in /etc/sudoers via vi sudo. but it's not working for me

Answer (score 8):

I think you can bring specific access to user and command with `visudo` something like this:

```
nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/osascript myscript.scpt
```

and with php:

```
@exec("sudo /path/to/osascript myscript.scpt ");
```

supposing `nobody` user is running apache.

Answer (score 4):

php: the bash console is created, and it executes 1st script, which call sudo to the second one, see below:

```
$dev = $_GET['device'];
$cmd = '/bin/bash /home/www/start.bash '.$dev;
echo $cmd;
shell_exec($cmd);
```

1. /home/www/start.bash

   > ```
   > #!/bin/bash
   > /usr/bin/sudo /home/www/myMount.bash $1
   > ```
2. myMount.bash:

   > ```
   > #!/bin/bash
   > function error_exit
   > {
   >   echo "Wrong parameter" 1>&2
   >   exit 1
   > }
   > ..........
   > ```

oc, you want to run script from root level without root privileges, to do that create and modify the /etc/sudoers.d/mount file:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/www/myMount.bash
```

dont forget to chmod:

```
sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/mount
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS
The shell has a pty (pseudo terminal device, same as you would have in i.e. a ssh session), and you can get the shell as root if desired. Not sure you need root to execute your script, but given you mention sudo it is likely.

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('/path/to/osascript myscript.scpt');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Run `sudo visudo` command then set `-%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL)` to `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` it will work.**

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use passthru to validate sudo before you actually use it:

```
passthru('sudo -v');
exec('sudo osascript myscript.scpt', $output, $status);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation trying to `exec()` a backend command and also getting `no tty present and no askpass program specified` in the web server error log. Original (bad) code:

```
$output = array();
$return_var = 0;
exec('sudo my_command', $output, $return_var);
```

A `bash` wrapper solved this issue, such as:

```
$output = array();
$return_var = 0;
exec('sudo bash -c "my_command"', $output, $return_var);
```

Not sure if this will work in every case. Also, be sure to apply the appropriate quoting/escaping rules on `my_command` portion.

Answer (score 0):

The best secure method is to use the crontab. ie Save all your commands in a database say, mysql table and create a cronjob to read these mysql entreis and execute via exec() or shell_exec(). Please read this [link](https://sanjaykumarns.blogspot.com/p/how-to-execute-root-level-privileged.html) for more detailed information.

- - - - - killProcess.php

Answer (score 0):

I think directly calling a sudo command might be difficult because you are setting up the whole server to work without a password.
Perhaps as an alternative you could setup a CRONjob as root and monitor a flag file.  Once the flag file exists it will run the osascript myscript.scpt and then delete the flag file.
This way you will keep SUDO secure from a config point of view and the server safer.  To run the script you just need to touch the flag file from PHP.
It would of course introduce a delay of however many minutes you running the CRON job.  It would also mean that you would have to redirect the output to a file and have a async monitor of the output, but it will depend on your application if this is a problem or not.

But it is an alternative that might protect the server.

Comment: I am not sure about storing commands in the database as this too could be abused.  I prefer to keep things more tight.  Running any command as root should be as secure as possible.