# Shutdown from php - giving apache permission

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am working on a embedded linux system with a web interface (apache). Basically I need to add shutdown and restart functionality to the web interface. However, I am running into permission issues when running:

exec("shutdown now") etc...when calling through the webpage(ie apache).

How the heck do I allow these commands to be called from apache?

Would prefer not to have to give apache full root permissions, but system security is not a huge deal in my case, so if that is the only way, how can I do that?

Comment: Add apache user to sudoers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec

Comment: It might be possible to give apache access to `/dev/initctl`, and if so, that might then allow it to shut down and restart the system, without having to use sudo or giving it root access. This is purely guesswork, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making Apache a sudoer is a dangerous move and I'd avoid it. I think QID is close on this... the easiest solution is to set up a cron job under root that runs every X seconds and checks for a file in a directory that apache can write to. Have apache add that file when you want to shut down, and the cron script should have a trigger that (a) removes the file and (b) restarts the machine.

Just be careful that it removes the file correctly and give yourself a pretty long cron delay when you're testing, or the server will just reboot continuously and that would be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing a good way to do this, I can offer an ugly hack solution: write a tiny daemon that runs as root and accepts commands to shut the system down, and have your PHP script communicate with the daemon through a reasonably-secured channel (for your definition of reasonable; maybe send a signal, maybe write to a file that the daemon watches, maybe just a network socket, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

be suer you know what you are doing:

exec("sudo ...

apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Using sudo is a good idea, but in that case it would be possible to limit apache's access to only certain commands, instead of giving it full root permissions.

Comment: yup all seems a little to dangerous to me.