# Shutdown linux using c# and mono

Tags: c#, soap, mono, shutdown

I am working on a cross platform project with c#/soap and php on Windows and Linux.

The idea is that when the user presses a button on the web interface it sends a soap request which will shutdown the server.

This is working fine on Windows but on Linux its not working, I don't see any reason why not as when I run the shutdown command manually on the server it works fine.

Below is the code that I am using

```
public bool shutdownServer()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    if (CommonTasks.getOperatingSystem() == CommonTasks.OperatingSystemType.Windows)
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s -t 0";
    }
    else if (CommonTasks.getOperatingSystem() == CommonTasks.OperatingSystemType.Linux)
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-h now";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    library.logging(classDetails + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, string.Format("Shutting down with the following {0} {1}", process.StartInfo.FileName, process.StartInfo.Arguments));
    process.Start();
    return true;
}
```

I can't see any reason why the linux section won't perform the shutdown but the windows version works fine. What am I doing wrong.

Just to be clear I am trying to shutdown the entire server, not the application.

Thanks for any help you can provide

**UPDATE **
Thanks for your suggestions, I think I'm getting somewhere. I found out the mono is running under wwwrun using janis method.

I've added wwwrun:www group to /etc/groups using `wwwrun:x:0`, I'm not sure if this is bit is correct or not, I don't know what the :x:0 is for.

I've added `%wheel ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown` to the sudoers file and restart apache.

When I run the soap service to perform the shutdown I get the following error in `/var/log/messages`

> Aug  3 23:28:01 dev-server sudo: pam_unix2(sudo:auth): conversation
>   failed
>   Aug  3 23:20:27 dev-server sudo:   wwwrun : pam_authenticate:
>   Conversation error ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ;
>   COMMAND=/sbin/shutdown -h now

I don't know where to go from here now, sorry if I'm asking a bit of a noob question, I'm fairly new to soap/linux/mono.

**UPDATE 2**
Have just found out something else, it works on Windows only if the browser is running on the local PC that is being shutdown. I've tried redirecting output from the command to see if it is returning an error and nothing is, so I can't find out why it is failing.

**UPDATE 3**
I've just found out something else, I have two windows PC, laptop and desktop both Windows 7 x64, from the desktop browser I can do the soap request to shutdown the laptop and visa versa, however, the problem I am having is with Windows Server and Linux, even local on the Windows server browser won't let me shut itself down via the soap request. Is there a way I can make it so Windows server will allow me to do the shutdown via the soap request, local and remote browser and how can I fix the problem with Linux.

**UPDATE 4**
Have just fixed the Windows problem, I needed to add the IIS user account as an administrator to allow it to perform the shutdown, so its just Linux I have a problem with now.

Comment: Does mono user got permission to shutdown sever? By default only root can do that

Comment: Oh really, is there a way to get mono to be able to do it

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8497774/1387612) is solution that should works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it solved but all of your suggestions did help especially @janisz and @David Harris.

In order to get Windows to work I had to add the IIS User (IUSR) to the administrator group on Windows Server 2008.

For linux I needed to run the command as sudoer as @janisz said. To do this I need to run the command visudo in order to add edit the sudoers file, I then added the following into the sudoers file.

```
User_Alias APACHE = wwwrun  
Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN = /sbin/shutdown APACHE
APACHE ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN
```

Then rebooted the server.

To execute the shutdown command on Windows wasn't any different as before but on Linux as @David Harris pointed running the command as `/sbin/sudo` and the arguements `/sbin/shutdown -h now`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I'd replace

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-h now";
```

with

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "/usr/bin/sudo";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/sbin/shutdown -h now";
```

and have the account that executes the shutdown script set up in the sudoers file with permission to execute /sbin/shutdown with no password.

Answer (score 2):

Probably mono user has not privileges to shutdown computer so there are following options:

1. Add monouser to power group (or any other group that can turn off machine) `useradd -G power monouser`
2. Add monouser to sudoers file with permission to run shutdown command without password.Than change code to call sudo before shutdown. Run `visudo` and type  `monouser  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown`
3. Change file permissions that monouser can execute it

**EDIT**
I've just realized that `shutdown` is not protected but in normal user $PATH there is no entry for `/sbin/` so probably adding full path to shutdown will help. So change `process.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown";` to `process.StartInfo.FileName = "/sbin/shutdown";`

Comment: I've tried doing a google about adding a mono user to sudoers but can't find anything on Google to do this, or even finding out which user account mono is running under, would it be running under the apache user or something different. Do you know of anywhere where I could find out this info. Thanks for your help

Comment: It's easy to verify, run `whoami > /tmp/whoami` instead of shutdown and read user name

Comment: thanks I think I'm getting somewhere, I've added some more info to the question as I am getting an error in /var/log/messages when I execute the soap method to do the shutdown

Comment: Did you try do it without sudo? Sudo may requires TTY and probably that's why you get error.

Comment: Tried it without sudo, and the error doesn't get displayed, but the shutdown still doesn't start