# Restart mysql within php browser, permissions issue?

Tags: php, permissions, restart, mysql

I would like to create a button on my website that restarts mysql (I realize this is really bad news). I am using ec2 which has really strict user permissions.

This is my php code, but it's not restarting the session.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mysql'])){
    exec("sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart");
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="submit" value="mysql" name="mysql">
</form>
```

This is my suders file ...

```
Cmnd_Alias RESTART_MYSQL  = /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
mysql ALL =NOPASSWD: RESTART_MYSQL
```

This doesn't work either...

```
Cmnd_Alias RESTART_MYSQL  = /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
apache ALL =NOPASSWD: RESTART_MYSQL
```

Comment: Your sudoers file specifies that the `mysql` user has permissions to restart the command. Your PHP script will not be running as the `mysql` user.

Comment: what is your real pronlem? may you can just cut connections by "KILL"?

Comment: it doesn't work when the user is Apache either.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec

Answer (score 1):

When you run **sudo**, you need to enter your password. SO, you can't use **sudo** in a script.