# Git WebHook will not pull (PHP)

Tags: php, git, webhooks

I have a PHP file, `hook.php`, that looks like this:

`` <?php
`cd .. && git pull`; ``

The file is located in `/var/www/oliverash.me/site/`. However, the git repository that needs to be pulled is `/var/www/oliverash.me/`. `./site` is the folder Apache looks to as the document root.

When I run the file in my browser, it does not seem to be pulling the repository.

I have also tried to echo the result, but the page is blank.

`` <?php
echo `cd .. && git pull`; ``

Comment: Does it require a password to do the pull?  Or is it using local file access?

Comment: No password. Using SSH but with no passphrase.

Comment: is php in safe_mode which doesn't let you out of this document root?

Comment: I run `echo `cd .. && pwd`` and that seemed to work fine, but I’m not sure if safe mode being enabled would restrict me from doing that. I’ll have a look and post back here when I’ve found out.

Comment: Check the apache error log for any error.

Comment: `error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't post a comment in reply to you, but I am assuming that you are running a *nix system.  You will be getting a permission denied if your apache/php daemons don't have permission to access `.git/`.  You can change the owner/group of the `.git/` directory recursively.  Or do a `chmod -R o+rw .git/*` to give everyone (ie, not owner, not group) access to read and write in the git directory, which should clear up the permissions error that you are getting.

**EDIT**
Just re-read the question, so what follows probably isn't needed, but leaving it just in case.

Though, doing that, you need to keep in mind that anyone with access to your server will be able to go to `http://myurl/.git/` etc to access those.  So as a security precaution, I would add a `.htaccess` file like:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
```

in the`.git` directory so that apache will deny access from a web browser to everything in there.

Comment: Many thanks. Almost sorted, I think. However, now I’m getting this error in `error_log`: `Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.^M
Host key verification failed.^M
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Start off trying `mkdir /var/www/.ssh` then `chmod o+rw /var/www/.ssh` to set up the `.ssh` directory with access for all.  Let me know what errors you may get after that.  That should help solve the first two, and hopefully it will solve the last one since the Host key should be able to be verified after.

Comment: Now I’m just getting this: `Host key verification failed.^M
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`. Why did it want a `.ssh` in `www`?

Comment: I think it wanted the `.ssh ` as apache's 'home' directory.
What happens when you run the command from the command line?  I am assuming it works correctly, but checking just in case.  If it works fine, you should be able to resolve it by copying from your `~/.ssh` in to `/var/www/.ssh` and doing a `chmod 0+r *` inside that directory.

Comment: After this I’m getting `fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/oliverash.me/.git/ORIG_HEAD.lock': Permission denied`. Should I `chmod o+r* /var/www/oliverash.me`?

Comment: I would think most in `/var/www/oliverash.me/` should already be `o+r`, but doing `chmod o+rw /var/www/oliverash.me/.git` should solve that.

Comment: So I got it working by creating a symbolic link from `/root/.ssh` to `/var/www/.ssh`, running `chmod o+r *` inside of `.ssh`, and then finally `chmod o+rw /var/www/oliverash.me/.git`. I think I can see why this was necessary – the `git pull` command worked through SSH because I was logged in as root, and that account had the SSH keys necessary for the git remote. The `apache` user didn’t. Is that right?

Comment: I would be interested in getting things working using the other method @pjz suggested, whereby I had a line to `/etc/sudoers`. I think this means I won’t have to worry about permissions on `.git` on future projects.

Comment: The `git pull` only gets so far, however, as these errors are now appearing in my `error_log`: http://hastebin.com/fimuloloru.coffee.

Comment: That is correct.

And adding to `sudoers` would work, but for the most part, you _never_ want your web service to have permission to run anything as the root user.  It would be better to add your apache user to a group that you give `+rw` access to directories with.  Though, since you created the symbolic link with `.ssh` you should have any more issue with other projects as well - just make sure you `+rw` the new `.git` directories that you end up creating.

Comment: Should I execute `chmod o+rw /var/www/oliverash.me` to solve this new error?

Comment: Those errors are because your apache user doesn't have permission to change within your pulled git.  Do a `chmod -R o+rw` to the base directory that git is using.

Comment: You learn fast!  Exactly that, might want to do it recursively though so add `-R` before the `o+rw`

Comment: You might be able to help with my next issue, too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918981/git-webhook-php-cannot-access-rubygem-command

Comment: Just run through all of this again – to clarify, the symbolic link didn’t work, so I had to actually copy the files.

Answer (score 1):

You've certainly got a permissions issue, maybe a couple.

1. The php page is going to execute as the apache user
2. That user must be able to write to the git repo in question
3. That user must be able to do the pull in question
4. You didn't specify what the source of the pull is, but if it's, for instance, a git: or ssh: repo, then that user will need perms (keys, username/password, whatever) to access the remote to do the pull from.
5. Just saw that it wants /var/www/.ssh - so you're using a ssh:// remote, which is fine, but since it's running as user apache (/var/www is user apache's homedir), it's looking for keys in /var/www/.ssh, which it's not finding, hence the failure.  Solutions:

   1. use sudo to switch to a user that does have perms and run the git pull as that user (in your php, do 'sudo git pull', and in your /etc/sudoers put a line allowing user apache to run the 'git pull' command)
   2. set up a .ssh/config file that specifies a `Host` that's the remote, a `User` to use to login, and an `Identity` that is the path to the private key that the remote will allow to ssh in and do the pull.

Comment: Is it the `apache` user or the `www` user?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh: As written, the `whoami` command outputs the username, that is `apache` in your case, the `/var/www` directory is the that user's home-directory.

Comment: I tried adding `apache ALL = (root) /usr/bin/git pull` to `/etc/sudoers`. Still getting the same error in my `error_log`: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. [Here’s my most recent `hook.php`](http://hastebin.com/lapowepupe.php).

Answer (score 1):

create webhook.php in the root or anywhere from where you can access it

$result = exec("cd /path/to/repo && git pull origin branch");

make sure the permission is 775 and user of your file and your site directory is www-data owner

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem with the user here that is executing the command.

According to your various comments, the system commands are executed as the user named  **`apache`** (homedir is `/var/www`). You can verify this by running the `whoami` command from within your PHP script:

```
<?php echo `whoami`;
```

That user named **`apache`** is commonly the user your webserver runs under, which then runs PHP which then runs the shell commands.

Obviously you want to run the command as some other user, but you have not shared so far the information which one.

Run the shell command under the right user and the problem should go away.

On a linux system, the command to run other commands under a different user is called `sudo`, another one `su`:

- [sudo(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)
- [su(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su)

Alternatively you can make use of suexec to execute PHP under a different user than the webserver user.

In any case you need to ensure that you have a user that is able to execute the git command. I have no clue how you tested that on your own, best way I know is to ssh into the server box, do the git pull manually and collect the needed data like user-name, homedirectory etc. .

Comment: `whoami` returns apache. If I precede the command with sudo, then I get the following error in my error_log: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: Yes the user is apache apache, www was only the basename of the  homedir. And then the tty error, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec and other similar ones. http://maymay.net/blog/2010/03/17/how-to-work-around-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo-without-sacrificing-security/