# Git WebHook (PHP) cannot access ruby environment, running jekyll as apache user

Tags: git, apache, jekyll, webhooks

I have a `post-merge` hook in my git repository that just runs the `jekyll` command.

When I run `git pull`, the `post-merge` runs with no problems.

However, I have setup a PHP file which will act as a WebHook for the remote:

```
$pull = `cd .. && git pull`;
echo $pull;
```

When I access this file, the git pull runs ([after some initial problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856907/git-webhook-will-not-pull-php/12890603)) and is successful. However, for some reason the `post-merge` fails. If I look inside of my Apache `error_log`, I find the following error:

`.git/hooks/post-merge: line 5: jekyll: command not found`

This is odd, considering the `post-merge` successfully runs jekyll when I do a manual `git pull` via SSH.

If I run use the full path to the executable as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918981/git-webhook-php-cannot-access-rubygem-command), I get this error in my `error_log`:

`/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory`

I installed Ruby through RVM.

How is it possible to have the `apache` user run `jekyll` with no problems?

**Edit:** Here is my current `post-merge`:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset GIT_DIR

source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p194

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/jekyll

echo "Deployed!"
```

When I run this as the `apache` user, I now get this error:

[image]

Node.js is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I was using RVM, I had to source that instead of Ruby directly. Not sure why, but it's working now.

My `post-merge` looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset GIT_DIR

/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm use 1.9.3

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/jekyll

echo "Deployed!"
```

Not perfect – rvm echoes a load of stuff which I don't want, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

I think this error is very clear:

```
jekyll: command not found
```

you should use the complete path to your `jekyll` command.

```
whereis jekyll
```

then execute the command with the full path like:

```
/usr/local/bin/jekyll --params
```

Here is a solution for the `ruby_noexec_wrapper` problem.

[/usr/bin/env ruby_noexec_wrapper fails with no file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127603/usr-bin-env-ruby-noexec-wrapper-fails-with-no-file-or-directory)

**Edit:**

```
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available
```

[ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: After adding `source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p194` to my `post-merge` ([see here](http://hastebin.com/kocilaguva.bash)), I’m now getting [this error](http://hastebin.com/munuhurafu.vbs). I think it’s because jekyll has plugins which are requiring gems, and they would need sourcing too… right?

Comment: You should first look at the first error: Could not find a JavaScript runtimehttps://github.com/sstephenson/execjs the gem is missing. So you should follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime

Comment: Hmm, if I run `jekyll` via SSH, I have no problems. I think I might have the gem, it’s just not got access?

Comment: I don't know what you do ;) but he can't find the JS runtime. Perhaps your path is wrong? Or your require not correct? Perhaps you run something what is not startet on with the SSH command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-3-1-error-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime everytime its the same. Install nodejs and test it again.

Comment: Then your gem is not working ;) there are not so much possibilities ;) then make a testscript and check the gem.

Comment: My gem works fine if I SSH and run `jekyll`, which suggests that the problem is because the WebHook, when run by user `apache`, does not have access to the gems.

Comment: And when you change to the apache user and test to run the command? su www-data -s /bin/bash or apache user.

Comment: There is your error: PERMISSION DENIED. Permission denied - /var/www/oliverash.me/site/2012/06/24/IMG_4411.html (Errno::EACCES)
To fix this problem change the owner or group of this file or the folder to apache.

Comment: I fixed that, so I can now run `su apache -s /bin/bash; jekyll` and it works. However, when the WebHook is triggered, I’m still getting this error in my `error_log`: http://hastebin.com/jeyijawohi.vbs

Comment: I have made a chat-room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/19335/git-webhook-php-cannot-access-ruby-environment?tab=general perhaps we can solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is we are in different time zones and countries i think. I am online now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding the following to my `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

The `rvm` installer should already have added

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

I added the `source` line above this and it fixed these issues.