# php impersonate user

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

What I am trying to do is run shell commands as the system `root` user from a web page.

From what I have researched, there is no way to impersonate a system user in PHP on Linux (CentOS 6.3 with PHP 5.4.13 to be exact).

So far I have installed `sudo` and added a line `apache ALL=(ALL) :NOPASSWD ALL` (for testing) to `/etc/sudoers`.  I have then created a simple php file in the root of my website:

```
<?php shell_exec('sudo -u root touch somefile'); ?>
```

and nothing happens, however, if I run:

```
<?php shell_exec('whoami'); ?>
```

I get `apache` as the result, so I know at least shell_exec is working.

If I try from the cli `su apache`, I get `This account is currently not available.` which I believe is because apache has nologin defined (?) `apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin`

So whats the right way to be able to run commands as root from php?

As an example of what I am trying to achieve by running as root, I would like to add certificates to `/etc/ssl/certs/https` using the following command line called from a web control panel:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 \
 -subj "/emailAddress=${ssl_email}/CN=ca.${domain_name}/OU=${ssl_organisational_unit}/O=${ssl_organisation}/L=${ssl_location}/ST=${ssl_state}/C=${ssl_country}" \
 -keyout "${certroot}/cacert.pem" -out "${certroot}/cacert.pem"
```

Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: have you tried writing the sudo command in a batch file, and calling that from PHP?

Comment: this is on linux so by batch file do you mean a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

ah ha!!! Got it!

Not long after I wrote that, I found [sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec)

The answer is to comment out `Defaults    requiretty` from `/etc/sudoers`