# Running python script from PHP - arguments

Tags: php, python

I have a python script that displays info about USB ports, which can be used to turn ports on/off. I want to run it from PHP.

I tried the following code without any options specified (which just displays info) and it worked:

```
$output = exec('python /home/ratta/usb_control.py');
echo  $output;
```

I then tried adding the necessary options but it doesn't turn the USB port off as  it should:

```
$output = exec('python /home/ratta/usb_control.py --hub 001:011 --port 3 --power 0');
echo  $output;
```

Any ideas anyone? The script runs fine when running it manually without PHP.

Thanks

Comment: I think I've found the problem - the python script needs to be run as sudo, which isn't happening from php. 

How can I run the python script as sudo using php?

Comment: Since apparently you've dealt with the problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec regarding the question in comment.