# FFMPEG-Php installation on Amazon EC2 linux AMI

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

I have installed FFMPEG on Amazon EC2 Linux AMI using [this](https://gist.github.com/gboudreau/f24aed76b4cc91bfb2c1) script now I am trying to install FFMPEG-PHP and after `./configure` it gives me this error on `make` command

```
 # make
/bin/sh /opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/ffmpeg  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing   -c /opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c -o ffmpeg-php.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/ffmpeg -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -c /opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ffmpeg-php.o


 In file included from /opt/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:42:0:
    /usr/local/include/ffmpeg/avcodec.h:43:21: fatal error: version.h: No such file or directory
     #include "version.h"
```

I have searched this a lot but couldn't manage to do it, Amazon support officer asked me to use CENTOS AMI instead of Linux AMI but I have everything hosted there, so I will appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thank you,

Hamza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FFPMEG is no longer supported and is not updated since 2008, So I have managed to do it using commands through PHP

so if anyone of you wants to use FFMPEG then use `exec` command but make sure you enter correct path like below

```
$ret = exec('ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/inputvid.mp4 -b:v 1300k -preset ultrafast /var/www/html/outputvid.mp4', $out, $err);
```

Comment: thank you for post - it helped me to install ffmpeg :) Also, I was able to use exec in php by @Dhunju_likes to Learn's help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec

Comment: Pleasure that I could help