# sudo command inside shell script and called by PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell, sed, centos

### Background

I have made a **PHP web application** to execute a **Linux Shell Script** to change the data in **network-scripts** of CentOS 7. In other words, this is a PHP web application that can change the IP in CentOS 7.

The script itself is good to change, I can run the script using SSH with proper arguments, the usage like the following:

```
sh ./ipchanger.sh <fileName> <oldIpAddress> <newIpAddress> <oldSubnetMask> <newSubnetMask> <oldGateway> <newGateway>
```

Sample usage:

```
 sh ./ipchanger.sh /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens32 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.205 PREFIX0=32 PREFIX0=24 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1
```

That will change the IP from `192.168.1.5` to `192.168.1.205` and the subnet mask will be changed from `255.255.255.255` to `255.255.255.0`. The gateway will remain unchanged.

---

### PHP Application

The data will be posted from a form processed with PHP. The code will check if the IP addresses are correct or not. If the arguments are collected and correct, my PHP code will call the shell script to make changes to the network-scripts.

Like this:

```
$retval = exec('sh /var/www/html/ipchanger/ipchanger.sh {$fileName} {$currentIpAddress} {$newIpAddress} {$currentSubnetMask} {$newSubnetMask} {$currentGateway} {$newGateway}');
```

That means:

```
$retval = exec('sh /var/www/html/ipchanger/ipchanger.sh /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens32 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.205 PREFIX0=32 PREFIX0=24 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1');
```

---

### Shell Scripts

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# My IP Changer

fileName="$1"
currentIpAddress="$2"
newIpAddress="$3"
currentSubnetMask="$4"
newSubnetMask="$5"
currentGateway="$6"
newGateway="$7"

`sudo sed -i -e "s/$currentIpAddress/$newIpAddress/g" ${fileName}`
`sudo sed -i -e "s/$currentSubnetMask}/$newSubnetMask/g" ${fileName}`
`sudo sed -i -e "s/$currentGateway/$newGateway/g" ${fileName}`
```

---

### Problem

The file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens32` doesn't changed at all. If I run the shell script in SSH (refer to sample usage in background chapter), it works! So my shell script should be fine.

---

### Other Trials

**1. Put echo in shell script to see if the arguments are in the correct position**
*Result: Yes.*
The arguments showed just like expected.

**2. Put 2>&1 behind the exec()**
*Result: Message showed.*
`sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. I don't know if `sed` needs root permission or not. So I put it in the shell script anyway to make the shell script execute smoother.

**3. Remove sudo in shell script**
*Result: In SSH, good; In PHP, message showed.*
`sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/sedJfDtCD: Permission denied`. I googled this message. When using `sed -i`, it will create a temporary file to store the original file in case the script messed up.

**4. Remove -i in sed command in shell script**
*Result: Failed.*
The script cannot perform its task.

---

### Other Information

**OS:** CentOS

**Web server type:** LAMP

**whoami:** apache

**Script usage:** Internal use. So I don't care about security issues

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Well, your problem is right there: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. `sudo` does not run when called from anything other than a tty (which is a login shell, as opposed to the PHP script you try to call it from).

Comment: Give your script the proper permissions and you won't even need to think about doing this.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec especially the `requiretty` part from `visudo`.

Comment: @l'L'l The file has chmod to 0777 in the following files: `index.php`, `ipchanger.sh`, `ifcfg-ens32` and the owner is root.

Comment: `chmod` is only part of it; you'll also need to modify the scripts owner `chown`.

Comment: Re I'L'I: The script owner is also root. The whole application is owned by root as I upload all of these files by root@SFTP.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Your suggestion can let PHP to use sudo now. If there is other method that won't use sudo and it will be better (like copy the file and edit it and overwrite the file). But thanks! Cheers.

Comment: @AkiEru you will need root access at some point.

Comment: @BartFriederichs so you think this is already the best way to solve? It's perfectly fine to me though. So don't keep it in mind. :)

Comment: @AkiEru no, I think it is a Bad Idea to change IP addresses (or any root access) from a PHP script. But that's not the point I guess.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I think I would add a command to remove apache from `/etc/sudoers`. Because this is just a one-time-use scripts.

Answer (score 0):

not directly for you right problem but i advice to add some security on such file change

and optimize the three last lines with:

```
`sudo sed -i -e "s/$currentIpAddress/$newIpAddress/g;s/$currentSubnetMask}/$newSubnetMask/g;s/$currentGateway/$newGateway/g" ${fileName}`
```

- the last `g` of each of your `s///` is normaly not necessary (only 1 change by line)

Comment: I am a newbie to Shell Script (started learning 3 days ago) so thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as user: apache/www-data or root if needed). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code.

```
//You could maintain your ipchanger.sh script and simply trigger that script
//through the shell, but the point of the shell project is that it lets you 
//trigger commands directly. in your case you could do this:

$ifFilePath = '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens32';    

$ifCfg= "DEVICE=ens32";
$ifCfg.= "\nIPADDR=192.168.1.205";
$ifCfg.= "\nPREFIX0=24";
$ifCfg.= "\n192.168.1.1";

$strCmd = "echo \'".$ifCfg."\' > \'".$ifFilePath."\'";

//But if you wanna stick with your script then:

$strCmd = "sh ./ipchanger.sh /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens32 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.205 PREFIX0=32 PREFIX0=24 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1";

//in either case the $strCmd is triggered like this:
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd($strCmd);
```

After the config file change you can then reload the interface config using the same shell:

```
$return2  = $shell->exeCmd('service network restart');
```