# www-data running command not working

Tags: php, nginx, sudo

I'm using nginx with php , and I would like to run some command with exec()
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php .

the current example work perfectly `echo exec('whoami');` but when I try with other command the output is empty.

the exec() is enabled on my php.ini and the safe mode is disabled , I also edited the sudoers `www-data  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`  but `sudo -u www-data cammand` still required a password

Any solution please, thank you all

Comment: Although it is probably a bad idea to do suck thing, you could check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec

Comment: I will try that, thx