# How to register user on ejabberd using php code?

Tags: php, sudo, ejabberd

I am trying to register user on ejabberd linux server.

I am using below php code

```
<?php
  $username = 'hello';
  $password = 'hello';
  $node = 'my ip';
  exec('sudo -S ejabberd /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl register '.$username.' '.$node.' '.$password.' 2>&1',$output,$status);
  if($output == 0){
        // Success!
        echo 'success';
   }else{
        // Failure, $output has the details
        echo '<pre>';
        foreach($output as $o){
                echo $o."\n";
        }
         echo '</pre>';
   }
?>
```

But when I execute the file i got following error :

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
        [sudo] password for daemon:
```

Also I found the solution from below url

[sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec)

but I am not getting how to use this

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can also use ejabberd_xmlrpc to register user using php but you have to change setting  in your ejabberd configuration file.Uncomment these lines in ejabberd configuration file-

```
 ## - 
  ##   port: 4560
  ##   module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
  ##   maxsessions: 10
  ##   timeout: 5000
  ##   access_commands:
  ##     xmlrpc:
  ##       commands: all
  ##   options: []
```

[for php sample check this link](https://www.mindstick.com/Forum/34110/how-to-register-user-on-ejabberd-using-php)