# File not created while using cp command in php

Tags: php, linux, copy

In my program I need to copy a file to a new file. I'm using the following php code to change the folder permission and copy existing file *test.php* to a new file (not already created) *test_1.php*.

```
exec('chmod -R 0777 /folder1/');
exec('sudo cp /folder1/test.php /folder/test_1.php');
```

But this is not creating and copying the *test_1.php* file.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing:

```
exec('sudo cp /folder1/test.php /folder/test_1.php');
```

Does your php code has 'sudo' permissions to move files ? You need to set permissions accordingly.

Please refer this:
[Sudo in php exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec)

Comment: @informer..thanks that was the problem. Its working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

your problem is in the first command,

PHP does not have the permission to perform this :

```
exec('chmod -R 0777 /folder1/');
```

as long as PHP http server api is running -usually and unless you have not changed this- under `www-data` user which is has no permissions to perform tasks like this.

you need as an sysadmin to give that folder `folder1` the 0777 permission first, then you may easily perform commands on it using php

another approach by giving `www-data` user the ownership of the folder,

but you will still have to perform this command as a super user [not recommended]

```
$ chown www-data folder1/
```

Comment: folder1 is having 0777 permission.

Comment: @Jenz so you don't need to use sudo :)

Comment: @Jenz `cp /folder1/test.php /folder/test_1.php` will do the trick ! :)