# Execute shell commands with PHP

Tags: php, shell, ssl, amazon-ec2, certbot

I am trying to execute this command using the shell_exec function from PHP:

```
shell_exec("cd /home/ec2-user; ./certbot-auto -n --apache -d mydomain.com");
```

When i execute direct from terminal the result is this:

```
Requesting to rerun ./certbot-auto with root privileges...
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mydomain.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Created an SSL vhost at /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf
Deploying Certificate to VirtualHost /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf
```

But when i execute in my app, my result is only the first line:

```
Requesting to rerun ./certbot-auto with root privileges...
```

How can i fix this?

Obs:

- I am trying to install Certbot SSL certificates.
- My app is in Amazon AWS
- I do not have much knowledge on servers.
- I am using Laravel 5.5 in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec) or google for "php sudoers".

Your script is running as apache user and hasn't rights as root; so you need to make an entry in /etc/sudoers (or put a file in sudoers.d) to be able to run certbot-auto as root from your script.