# sudo doesnt have access even though it is added with sudo visudo

Tags: php, sudo

I get this error when running a program from `www-data`.

Error

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

But I have added the following to `sudo visudo`

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/bin/poppler-0.65.0/build/utils/pdfimages
```

The path `/var/bin/poppler-0.65.0/build/utils/pdfimages` is correct.. I have tested it from a terminal.

Command

> sudo /var/bin/poppler-0.65.0/build/utils/pdfimages -list
>   data/scan_voucher/17.pdf

Comment: How and where are you running this command? Are you running this through PHP?

Comment: yes, its running from nginx and php

Comment: So that is your issue, when you run from php there is no tty for the sudo. You need to disable that. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248463/running-ssh-command-from-php-gives-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-s and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec

Comment: any feedback on the comment I provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that already setting up `sudo visudo` correctly, I will first take a look at `Tarun Lalwani` links, specially the part about disable requiring tty in your sudoers :

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```

Try to do the same command but with flag **-S** actived (*sudo -S yourcommand*)

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the
>   standard input instead of the terminal device.

If it doesn't work for you, you can try a `trick` that seems to work like this one (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)):

```
echo '' | sudo -S your_command
```

That will send an empty password to first prompt to enter password.

How are you executing this from PHP? Try with:

```
@exec("sudo /var/bin/poppler-0.65.0/build/utils/pdfimages -list data/scan_voucher/17.pdf");
```

Hope that it helps!