# Python script execed by PHP ignores arguments

Tags: python, php, raspberry-pi3

I'm a noob so bear wtih me... 
I have ran into an issue where my Python script, which I start from Apache server by PHP, ignores all other arguments except the first one.

PHP GETS variables and uses them as arguments when starting the script like so:

```
echo exec( "sudo python3 /var/www/html/motor_arg.py $n1 $t1 $n2 $t2" );
```

The Python srip starts but everything except `$n1` is ignored and 
the scrip ends. When I run the script from shell like so:
 `python3 motor_arg.py 10 5 20 5` it works just fine...

I honestly have no idea why this happens. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET request variables end up in a ["superglobal"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). You most likely need something like this: `$n1 = $_GET['n1']` or `$n1 = $_REQUEST['n1']`. I hope you *really* trust anyone making requests to this server.

You're also going to run into issues with `exec('sudo')`. There are some answers here, also very insecure. [sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec)

Comment: I didn't mention it bu I am using `$n1 = $_GET['n1']`. Security is not  at all a priority on this project.

Comment: you say `$n1` comes through, but the rest do not? I would try echoing back your variables or even exec("echo $n1 $t1 $n2 $t2 > test.txt") and see if they are being properly initialized