# how to run php exec with sudo on live server

Tags: php, laravel, centos, digital-ocean

I have a simple scripts that create folder for every user that sign up, it works perfectly fine on local but after pushing to live server it does not work... I discovered that it require `sudo` password. I google around and all suggested that I should edit sudoer by running visudo but nothing work.

```
 $sudoPassword = \Config::get('app.sudoPassword');

 $sudo = "echo $sudoPassword | sudo -S ";

 $createDir =  "cd ../../merchants && mkdir ".$merchant->identity." && cd ".$merchant->identity;

echo exec($createDir);
```

my question is, how should I make exec to run as root? I'm using centOS in digitalocean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend running the script as `sudo`. A better alternative is to give permission to the web server (`www-data` user) to write to the `../../merchants` directory.

First add yourself to the `www-data` group by running the command below.

```
usermod -a -G www-data <your-username>
```

Then give the ownership of the `merchants` folder to the `www-data` group using the command below.

```
chgrp www-data merchants
```

Lastly give the correct permissions to the `merchants` folder using the command below.

```
chmod g+rwxs merchants
```

Hope this helps you solve your issue.

---

**EDIT**

On CentOS, you should use `apache` instead of `www-data`.

Comment: usermod: group 'www-data' does not exist (I'm using centos not ubuntu)

Comment: I have edited my answer. CentOS has `apache` instead of `www-data`. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, just a suggested improvement to your code. Instead of using sudo I would stick to @tamrat's solution. This is more ment as a comment but is too long to be a comment.

Instead of using php's `exec` function I would recommend you using Symfony's process component which is already available in your Laravel project.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
```

Use:

```
$createDir =  "mkdir /full/path/to/merchants/".$merchant->identity." && cd /full/path/to/merchants/".$merchant->identity;

$process = new Process($createDir);
$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

I also suggest that you use full paths rather then relative paths (if possible for your use-case) so you don't do actions in another directory when you re-use the code from another file. If not make sure you allways are in the correct path by validating properly.